# Does Angular memoize inline *ngIf condition statements?

Tags: angular

Does Angular memoize inline *ngIf condition statements? If I have for example:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="inputModels.length < 200">
```

is "inputModels.length < 200" recalculated every time change detection runs, or it's stored until inputModel changes?

Comment: Yes it'll change based on the condition.

Comment: Yes, the Angular's DOM is made basically using `reflections`, hence everytime a binded object changes, angular update only the html part related to that object. You can prevent Angular for doing this by using the `OnPush` strategy, and with `ChangeDetectionRef` you can programmatically update the component's view.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi, your comment is worth an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, Angular take care of this for you!

This mechanism works because Angular generate a `factory` for every component.

*A component factory mostly consists of the view nodes generated by the compiler as a result of template parsing.*

Since a factory component is a large topic, I'll just stop at this function: `updateRenderer`

The `updateRenderer` take care about updating the component's DOM when needed.

Every component, by default, is added to a `TreeRenderList`, an array of objects. Angular use that array for a lot of things. The most important two feature, in my personal opinion, about that, are these two:

- Update the component's DOM.
- Update the component's binding when they change

> Update the component's binding when they change, what does it mean?

Let's take an easy example to exaplain this.

```
    export class AppComponent {
      @Input() myInput: string;
    }

<p>{{myInput}}
```

We know that eveytime `myInput` change we see the changes in the relative html (by default). And this works becasuse of the `TreeRenderList` and the `updateRenderer` function.

> Can I prevent Angular to update the component's DOM?

Yep! and it's very easy. If we generate a component using the cli (`ng g c component-name`) it's decorator will be something like that:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'xxx.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['xxx.component.css'],
})
```

But there a lot of properties we can specify. One of it is `changeDetection`.

By default Angular use the `Default` strategy, meaning that the framework will decide on how and when update the component's DOM.

We can change it to be `OnPush`. By doing that we are telling Angular that it doesn't need  to update the component's DOM on its logic. Adding this property to the decorator, will result like this:

```
 @Component({
        changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
        selector: 'my-component',
        templateUrl: 'xxx.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['xxx.component.css'],
    })
```

If we try now to update the `@Input`, we will not see any changes. That's where `ChangeDetectionRef` comes in our help. In orded to use it, we need to `inject` it into the component and we can use `this.changeDetectionRef.detectChanges()` to programmatically tell Angular to update the component's DOM.

I wrote an in-depth guide on `ChangeDetectionRef` here, if you want to read it: https://medium.com/@sciampi.jacopo/angular-performances-a-guide-to-change-detection-b8a02c0b7b00

Comment: "A component factory mostly consists of the view nodes generated by the compiler as a result of template parsing." - so, even if I have default change detection strategy, if nothing changes in my component, angular is NOT recreating my component and reuses its view nodes created previously thus *ngIf is not "recalculated" on every frame, right?

Comment: Exactly. when something changes, only the relative node gets rendered again. You can see this if you open your developer console and select "Elements" tab. Try to change something (maybe with a button) you'll see that only one part of the DOM is changing.

Answer (score 0):

As the variable inputModel change condition also check at that time.*NgIf detects changes.Hence changes are made to inputModel variable condition gets check